# JUnit Testing: It throws 2 exceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

Here is my class that needed to test:

```
package testing;

public class Money {

    private int Amount;
    private String Currency;

    public int getAmount(){return Amount;}

    public String getCurrency(){return Currency;}

    public Money(int amount, String currency){
        Amount= amount;
        Currency= currency;
        }

    public Money addMoney(Money m){

        return (new Money(getAmount()+m.getAmount(),getCurrency()));
    }
```

here is my JUnit test class

```
package testing;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MoneyTest {

    @Test
    public void testAddMoney() {
        Money m1 = new Money (20,"DH");
        Money m2 = new Money(10,"DH");
        Money expected = new Money(30,"DH");
        Money result = m1.addMoney(m2);
        assertTrue(result.equals(expected));
    }


    @Test
    public void testEquals(){
        Money m1 = new Money (20,"DH");
        Money m2 = new Money(10,"DH");

        assertTrue(!(m1.equals(null)));
        assertEquals(m1, m1);
        assertEquals(m1, new Money(20,"DH"));
        assertTrue(!m1.equals(m2));


    }
```

When I run the test, it throws the first exception:

```
 java.lang.AssertionError 
at testing.MoneyTest.testAddMoney(MoneyTest.jaba:15)15 is the number of line : assertTrue(result.equals(expected));
```

and second one :

```
java.lang.AssertionError at testing.MoneyTest.testEquals(MoneyTest.java:26) 26 is the number of line: assertEquals(m1, new Money(20,"DH"));
```

What is the problem ???

Comment: Well you haven't overridden equals in `Money`...

Answer (score 4):

You **Money** class didn't override **equals** method, so

```
assertTrue(result.equals(expected));
```

Use **equals** method from **Object** class, and 2 instances are not equals.

Either override **equals** method on your **Money** class, or change the test

```
assertEquals(expected.getAmount(), result.getAmount());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two objects, `expected` and `result`.  You know in your mind that these are equal if the amount and currency are the same, but how is the program to know that?  Imagine a `Person` class with `name` and `dob` fields.  Two people who share the same name and were born on the same day must be represented by different `Person` objects.

Your rules for equality must be encoded in a `Money.equals` method which will overide the default `Object.equals` method.

To go further, you may want `Money` to implement the `Comparable` interface  by adding a `compareTo` method.  Then you can sort `Money` objects in a natural way.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, objects are identified by jvm using hashcode !! Person class can have many instances with different hashcode. Its good to override hashcode() of Object class whenever you override equals() of Object class.